# send email with text in email body and not as attachment

Tags: linux, email

I want to send the output of a script as a email but in the body of the email and not as an attachment. The command I am using-

```
python script.py 2>/dev/null | grep -v OK  | mail -s "check" abc@gmail.com
```

How to send the output of the script i.e. the lines left after `python script.py 2>/dev/null | grep -v OK` as a email body and not as an attachment?

Comment: That's what it should do already. There's nothing there that creates an attachment.

Comment: @Barmar, it is creating a file names 'noname' and sending the output in that file

Comment: What does the output of `script.py` look like? Is it just plain text?